# Add SNORT rules to my detection system

Tags: snort, intrusion-detection

Could any one give me some rules to test Snort (ARP,ICMP,TCP,UDP) and ensure that my system work properly against attacks like DOS or MITM.

Answer (score -1):

alert tcp any any -> any any (flags: S; msg:" Possible TCP dos detection"; flow: stateless; detection_filter: track by_dst, count 1000, seconds 1; sid: 10004;rev:1;)